# Is it formally correct to say that 2*n = O(2*n)?

Tags: big-o

Yes, it is obvious fact that `2*n = O(n)`, and `O(n)` is shorter notation than `O(2*n)`, but if we write `O(2*n)` - would it be incorrect?

I don't see any conflicts in the definition...
There exists `M`:
`|2*n| <= M * |2*n|` for all `x >= x0`

Or it would be just not accepted in math/programming community to write like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,

```
O(n) = O(2n)
```

because `n in O(2n)` and `2n in O(n)`.

thus both is correct. But it is *convention* to use the shortest notation of a class, and if you are asked about the complexity *class* in a test, they may be referring to the *shortest* name.